# How does this ActiveRecord 'where' clause work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have this statement:

```
myuser.orders.exists?(['(orderstatus = ?) ', statusid])
```

It returns true since there is an orderstatus that matches the statusid.

Next I have:

```
myuser.orders.where('id not in (?)', nil).exists?(['(orderstatus = ?) ', statusid])
```

This returns false where I thought it might return true since there are no ids that are nil.

Then I have:

```
myuser.orders.where(nil).exists?(['(orderstatus = ?) ', statusid])
```

This returns true.

My question is why does the middle statement return false?  It doesn't complain or throw any errors.  I guess I'm using nil wrong, but can someone explain?

Comment: Look in your log at the query generated by the second statement. If it doesn't offer an explanation to your question, post it here as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having trouble with SQL's NULL. The `where` in the middle one:

```
where('id not in (?)', nil)
```

becomes this SQL:

```
id not in (null)
```

and that's equivalent to this:

```
id != null
```

But the result of `id != null` is neither true nor false, the result is NULL and NULL in a boolean context is false; in fact, `x = null` and `x != null` result in NULL for all `x` (even when `x` itself is NULL); for example, in PostgreSQL:

```
=> select coalesce((11 = null)::text, '-NULL-');
 coalesce 
----------
 -NULL-
(1 row)

=> select coalesce((11 != null)::text, '-NULL-');
 coalesce 
----------
 -NULL-
(1 row)

=> select coalesce((null = null)::text, '-NULL-');
 coalesce 
----------
 -NULL-
(1 row)

=> select coalesce((null != null)::text, '-NULL-');
 coalesce 
----------
 -NULL-
(1 row)
```

MySQL and every other reasonably compliant database will do the same thing (with possibly different casting requirements to make the NULL obvious).

The result is that `where(id not in (?)', nil)` always yields an empty set and your existence check will always fail on an empty set.

If you want to say "all the rows where `id` is not NULL" then you want to say:

```
where('id is not null')
```

If your `id` is a primary key (as it almost certainly is), then `id` will never be NULL and you can leave that `where` out completely.

---

When you hand `where` just a `nil`:

```
where(nil)
```

`where`'s argument parsing logic will ignore the `nil` completely and `where(nil)` will be the same as `where()` and `where()` does nothing at all to the query. The result is that the first and third queries are identical as far as the database is concerned.